# Escape an already encoded json string

Tags: javascript, php, json, encode

at the moment i have to work with some json strings where the quotes are not correctly escaped. The strings looks like this

```
{ "foo" : "hello my name is "michael"" }
```

Is there any realistic chance in JS/PHP to escape the quotes in the value without doing it manually so i can parse the string?

Comment: How was this string generated?

Comment: json_encode() so i can only assume that there were some &quot; in the value that got converted back to " after the encode that's why they are not escaped.

Comment: json_encode will convert `"` to `\"`.

Comment: Maybe view source on the page, they may really be &quot;

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided us much to work with, but it looks like you're generating the json something like this way:

```
$userInput = $_GET['userInput'];
$json = '{ "foo" : "' . $userInput . '" }';
```

This is pretty bad. Here's the appropriate way to generate the json safely:

```
$outputData = array(
  "foo" => $_GET['userInput']
);
$json = json_encode($outputData);
```

See the reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

As to your original question, Is there any realistic chance in JS/PHP to escape the quotes? No. Suppose the "actual value" of the string is a series of paragraphs containing quote marks, you know, like a continuation of a quotation, where each paragraph starts with a `"`. No, that is not able to be fixed.

You need to fix the *source* of your json. If you are getting that json string from some third-party service, you need to tell them that the strings they are sending you is **not valid json**.